# Creating a calculator in C

Tags: c

How can I create a calculator in C without using `if else` and `switch case` ?

Here is the code so far :

```
void main()

{

    int a,b,sum,sub,pro,divide; /** sum is for addition,,sub is for subtraction,,pro is for product,,divide is for division**/
    char operator;
    clrscr();      
    printf("enter a value:");
    scanf("%d",&a);      
    printf("enter another value:");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("enter a operator:");
    scanf("%c",&operator);

    operator=='+';
    sum=a+b;
    printf("\nAnswer=%d",sum);
    operator=='-'
   sub=a-b;
    printf("\nAnswer=%d",sub);
    operator=='*';
    pro=a*b;
    prinf("\nAnswer=%d",pro);
    operator=='/';
    printf("\nAnswer=%d",divide);
    getch();  

}
```

Comment: What part of it doesn't work?  Also, you declare `divide` as your variable, but then call it as `division` at the bottom of your code.

Comment: ok man i will add it at homework  but if u help then plz tell me the soloution

Comment: i change this error too little bobby divide is divide at the bottom of my code thanks for helping

Comment: -1 In `C`, the proper "signature" of main is `int main(void)`. You need the right `#include` for a proper program. `clrscr()` is not in any Standard I know of. You should test the return value of `scanf`. **I believe `operator` is a keyword in `C++` and therefore an error in your program**. `getch` is not defined in any Standard I know of.

Comment: @pmg: all good remarks. `operator` is indeed a keyword used for operator overloading, `getch()` is part of Borland's `conio.h`, as is `clrscr()`, `int main() { ...` declaration (without `void`) is C++ standard. Also, `operator=='*';` does nothing by itself. These should be `if-else` statements or a `switch-case`. `operator=='-' sub=a-b;` is a syntax error.

Comment: What is the motivation for creating a program that doesn't use basic control structures?  Is this a condition of the assignment?  If so, what the hell does the instructor think he's teaching apart from bad practice?  The most *pointless* assignments are the "tricky" ones; you're never going to write code like that as a professional (hopefully), and it doesn't teach you anything useful.

Comment: @mingos: I just made that note about `operator` because the initial post was tagged `c++`. Now that the post has been edited it doesn't make all that sense :(

Comment: @pmg: I would still be cautious with using reserved words. Just in case ;)

Comment: @John Bode: You are absolutely right the instructor is really out of his mind. It is 1st assignment of our 1 semester. i am very thankfull to all of u for trying to help me out.

Comment: The reason for writing code like this is that it is branch free.  Branches slow down the execution of code since they can cause the pipeline to stall and inhibit the running of instructions in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick. It avoids using `if else` and `switch` by taking advantage of the fact that comparing the operator to either of `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` will return `1` for only one of the comparisons and `0` for the rest. Therefore the result is the sum of these comparisons, multiplied by the mathematic expression that corresponds to each operator:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    float a,b,result;
    char oper [2];
    printf("enter a value:");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("enter another value:");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("enter an operator:");
    scanf("%1s", oper);
    result = (oper[0] == '+') * (a + b) +
             (oper[0] == '-') * (a - b) +
             (oper[0] == '*') * (a * b) +
             (oper[0] == '/') * (a / b);
    printf("%4.2f %s %4.2f = %4.2f\n", a, oper, b, result);
}
```

When saved to a file called `calculator.c` the following command will compile it:

```
gcc calculator.c
```

The output will be called `a.out` and it can be run like this:

```
./a.out
enter a value:24
enter another value:4
enter an operator:/
24.00 / 4.00 = 6.00
```

I've been using `gcc (GCC) 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2)` but I'm sure other versions will work just as well.

Let me know if I pass your assignment ;-)

Comment: I wonder, is the ternary operator considered an if for the purpose of this assignment?

Comment: @Hogan, yeah, good question. It does not use the `if` and `else` keywords, so I assume that it's not, but you never know. I would definitely hand in both solutions just to be sure.

Comment: The first solution is pretty neat, +1 for that :)

Comment: @ klausbyskov same the answer i got again n again and it doesn't work

Comment: @pmg Hehe, ok. Does it look better now?

Comment: @klaus byskov: i am really thank full but i wanna know are u a programmer by profession or one more thing that y did u type this:

Comment: @sam yes and I typed it for fun. I don't usually write code in `C` so I just wanted to do it to show myself that I could.

Comment: char oper [2];            scanf("%1s", oper);
    result = (oper[0]                                  just tell me the logic so i can use it in future in my different pro grammes and thanksss alot and more then alot u give be a big favor.

Comment: @ klaus byskov:and give me one more favor tell me some books about C which u think are good enough for understanding C language deeply

Comment: @sam, this one is quite good: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've thought of a solution that satisfies the condition of the assignment and isn't *totally* retarded.

You can create a function for each operation; it takes the two inputs as arguments and returns the result.  You can then create a table of pointers to those functions, indexed by the operator character.

Then you can execute the function through the pointer.

```
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
  return a * b;
}

/**
 * do the same for add, subtract, and divide
 */

int main(void)
{
  int a, b;
  char op;
  /** 
   * create an array of pointers to functions indexed by 
   * character values; we will only be using four of these entries,
   * but this allows us to index the array using the operator
   * character directly instead of having to do any mapping.
   * We're trading some unused space for simplicity.
   */
  int (*func_table[128])(int, int);

  /**
   * Set the table entries for each operator.
   */
  func_table['*'] = multiply;
  /**
   * Do the same for each of '-', '+', '/'
   */
  ... 

  /**
   * After reading in a, b, and the operator, execute
   * the function through the lookup table
   */
  result = (*func_table[op])(a, b);
```

Presto; no control structures.

I was reluctant to post this for a couple of reasons.  First, it basically gives away the store.  Second, I doubt you've discussed function pointers in class yet.  I have no idea what your instructor expects; I doubt it's this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve it by pushing the operator and values onto a stack, and then just "execute" the stack.

Since this probably is a homework, I leave you with the task to implement the it :)

Comment: how to do that if u tell me this it is more helpfull for me

Comment: Then you have the problem of creating a stack without using `if` or `switch`, which may be even harder.

Comment: @ Pete I assume that an fixed array of a reasonable size and a position counter would do.

Answer (score 1):

As is remarked in the comments, the code is ridden with problems. Try this simple `switch-case` statement:

```
switch(op) {
    case '*': printf("%d",a*b); break;
    case '/': printf("%d",a/b); break;
    case '+': printf("%d",a+b); break;
    case '-': printf("%d",a-b); break;
    default: printf("Unknown operator."); break;
}
```

You'll handle the rest, right?

[EDIT]

OK, I thought it was SUPPOSED to use a `switch-case`.

How about this:

```
int result = 0;
result = (op == '*') ? a * b : result;
result = (op == '/') ? a / b : result;
result = (op == '+') ? a + b : result;
result = (op == '-') ? a - b : result;
printf("%d",result);
```

There's no `if-else` or `switch-case` :) You can also nest the statements if you wish (but that's unreadable).

Comment: As per the question, `switch` is not allowed.

Comment: thanks for the solution but it also don't work any thing else i will be thank full

Answer (score 0):

In `C` comparisons have a value. 1 if true, 0 if false. Maybe you can use that instead of the forbidden `if`

```
(operator == '+') /* this is either 0 or 1 */
(operator == '-') /* this is either 0 or 1 */
(operator == '*') /* this is either 0 or 1 */
(operator == '/') /* this is either 0 or 1 */
```

Comment: i will try it by write it in your way like (operator=='+') but not worked yet any other solution

Comment: What you should do is tell your teacher the SO community hates him/her for creating such stupid assignments :-)

Comment: hehe. I think that it's ok to make the students think outside the box a little bit, but I agree that this has close to no practical use, which should be stated as part of the assignment (something that I'm sure that it has not been).

Comment: hehehe i will try to send your message that SO community hates him

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()

{

    int a,b,sum,sub,pro,divide; /** sum is for addition,,sub is for subtraction,,pro is for product,,divide is for division**/
    char operator;
    clrscr();      
    printf("enter a value:");
    scanf("%d",&a);      
    printf("enter another value:");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("enter a operator:");
    scanf("%c",&operator);

    operator=='+'? printf("%d,a+b"): ;
    //same goes for all the other operators

    getch();  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it gonna be work like this too

```
# include "stdio.h"
# include "conio.h"
 void main()
    {
float a , b;
char c;

printf("Value 1:");
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("value 2:");
scanf("%f",&b);
printf("Enter a operator[ + - * /]\n");
c=getche();

(c=='+')&&(printf("\nAnswer is:%3.2f",a+b));
(c=='-')&&(printf("\nAnswer is:%3.2f",a-b));
(c=='*')&&(printf("\nAnswer is:%3.2f",a*b));
(c=='/')&&(printf("\nAnswer is:%3.2f",a/b));
getch();
    }
```